# Having trouble inserting into heap

Tags: c++, heap

Below is my C++ code for inserting into a heap. The value for k is inserted but it's inserted at the bottom. I expected it to heapify with that while loop.

```
void Insert(heap1* myHeap, int k)
{
    (myHeap->size)++;
    int i = myHeap->size;

    while (i > 1 && myHeap->H[i/2].key < k)
    {
        myHeap->H[i].key = myHeap->H[i/2].key;
        i = i/2;
    }
    myHeap->H[i].key = k;
}
```

I do have a heapify procedure that I tried to use for this before this attempt that I know works within my other heap procedures. I just can't get it to work within Insert so I went with the above route. Below is heapify just in case its useful:

```
void heapify(heap1* myHeap, int i)
{
    int l = 2 * i;
    int r = 2 * i + 1;
    int largest;

    if (l <= myHeap->size && myHeap->H[l].key > myHeap->H[i].key)
        largest = l;
    else
        largest = i;
    if (r <= myHeap->size && myHeap->H[r].key > myHeap->H[largest].key)
        largest = r;
    if (largest != i)
        {
        myHeap->H[i].key = myHeap->H[i].key + myHeap->H[largest].key;
        myHeap->H[largest].key = myHeap->H[i].key - myHeap->H[largest].key;
        myHeap->H[i].key = myHeap->H[i].key - myHeap->H[largest].key;
        heapify(myHeap, largest);
    }
}
```

If someone could lead me in the right direction on how to get it to restore its heap properties, I would largely appreciate it.

Comment: Not that it matters at this point, but including the *declaration* of what `heap1` actually *is* rather than us having to guess would be likely beneficial. And I'm not entirely sure why you even have it as a struct at all except to pin the size attribute along side the array.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code:

```
void insert(int heap[], int *n, int item){
    (*n)++;
    heap[*n] = item;
    reheapify_upward(heap, *n); 
}

void reheapify_upward(int heap[],int start){
    int temp,parent;
    if(start>1){
        parent=start/2;
        if(heap[parent]<heap[start]){
             temp=heap[start];
             heap[start]=heap[parent];
             heap[parent]=temp;
             reheapify_upward(heap,parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for more help you can visit this blog: [Basic Codings](https://basiccodings.blogspot.com)